# PHP Code Sniffer no VS Code : Como faço para ignorar determinada regra para não ficar recebendo erros?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Quero usar php code sniffer para estudar e ao mesmo tempo me obrigar a seguir os padrões das PSRs porem não quero seguir a regra que me obriga a comentar todo arquivo e toda função que eu criar.

Essa regra, na minha visão, mais atrapalha do que ajuda em um ambiente de estudos. A mesma gera erro até no meu arquivo de autoload e como não achei uma extensão no VS Code que de um autocomplete com os comentários quando eu crio uma função ou quando crio um arquivo .php quero remover este requisito do code Sniffer.

Seguem os erros que recebo toda hora:

> Missing file doc comment (PEAR.Commenting.FileComment.Missing)
>
> Missing doc comment for function autoload()
>   (PEAR.Commenting.FunctionComment.Missing)

Comment: você pode configurar as regras que seu projeto vai seguir criando um arquivo de configuração (https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Configuration-Options). Depois de configurar as regras de acordo com seu objetivo, configure sua extensão para usar as suas regras.

Comment: dentro do diretorio do code sniffer eu renomeei o arquivo CodeSniffer.conf.dist para CodeSniffer.conf e dentro dele esta a config:      
<?php
 $phpCodeSnifferConfig = array (
  'default_standard' => 'PSR2',
  'report_format' => 'summary',
  'show_warnings' => '0',
  'show_progress' => '1',
  'report_width' => '120',
)
?>
Aparentemente agora só a PSR-2 esta em funcionamento porem eu gostaria que as demais também funcionassem (MySource, PEAR, PSR1, PSR12, PSR2, Squiz and Zend)

Comment: Minha ideia e só excluir a regra PEAR.Commenting.FileComment.Missing e PEAR.Commenting.FunctionComment.Missing . Em phpcs.xml tem essa possibilidade de exclusão de regras mas aparentemente estou fazendo errado pois após adicionar as regras   <exclude name="PEAR.Commenting.FileComment"/>
  <exclude name="PEAR.Commenting.FunctionComment"/> nada acontece

Comment: Por praticidade, eu adotaria só o PSR-12, que já inclui a PSR-1. O que pode estar acontecendo é seu arquivo phpcs.xml não estar sendo considerado pela extensão.

Comment: Creio que seja isso mesmo porem tentei sem sucesso descobrir o porque ele esta sendo desconsiderado, minha solução foi exatamente essa quando especifico a PSR-12 a PSR-1 e 2 ficam em funcionamento e justas elas já trazem um a agradável ao código. Agradeço a atenção e as sugestões.

Answer (score 2):

Dentro do diretório do code sniffer eu renomeei o arquivo
`CodeSniffer.conf.dist` para `CodeSniffer.conf` e dentro dele esta a config:

```
<?php 

$phpCodeSnifferConfig = array ( 
    'default_standard' => 'PSR2', 
    'report_format' => 'summary', 
    'show_warnings' => '0', 
    'show_progress' => '1', 
    'report_width' => '120', 
) 

?>
```

Em 'default_standard' renomeei o atributo de PSR2 para PSR12 que abrange outras PSRs. Infelizmente isto desativa outros padrões que o php code sniffer traz como o PEAR mais mesmo assim a alteração trouxe mais legibilidade para meus códigos.